# Inertness how to go around base constructor

Tags: c#, constructor

Let's say I have a father and son who should be both non abstract and i wont to go around the father c'tor what I have done is this :

```
 public class D
{
    public D(int x) { }

    public D()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("D:constructor");
    }

}
public class E:D
{
    public E() : base(1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("E:constructor");
    }
```

}

Is there another way more elegant to go around the father constructor ?

EDIT: this is just a sample I do have a reason for the inertness is at a god practice or just cause the c'tor is different i should build another design?

Comment: "what?" is too short for a comment, but perfect for that case.

Comment: What is not elegant about this? If you want to use the inherited constructor you are going about it the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way base constructor's are handled in c#. The only more elegant solution I could suggest is to do very little in your default constructor within your father class. Possibly only initializing proper attributes, or maybe not doing anything. That way if you don't want it to output "D:constructor" you can still use the default constructor for E, without calling the base constructor that requires an int.

The issue isn't with the way it was designed, it's with the way you are creating your constructors.

Comment: so the best way is to use a virtual meethod and it would be the one who changes ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get around the base constructor. Even of you implement the above, you're still going through 'a' constructor, but that's the best you can do.